# How solve the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" problems in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got an "Acces-Control-Allow-Origin" problem.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/users' from origin 'http://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So I added the header authorizations on my Express server to expose the API to an other service.

This my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(res){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:5001");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Mehods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
}); 

const users = require('./api/user');
app.use('/users', users);

const user_has_question_response = require('./api/user_has_question_response');
app.use('/user_has_question_response', user_has_question_response);

const question = require('./api/question');
app.use('/question', question);

const response = require('./api/response');
app.use('/response', response);


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Unfortunately, I now have an infinite loop in my Express server.
There is not error to analyze on my console.
What should I do ?

Comment: `METHODS` not `MEHODS`. Please read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

Comment: Also your "middleware" doesn't call next, so is the only thing any request ever hits. Either read up on how to correctly implement Express middleware, or use an existing implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

example:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8000')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that you should read about CORS, but there is a package named express cors
or similar, with it you can specify origins, which are allowed, or you can allow all origins of requests which can be dangerous.

temporary solution:

```
app.use(cors())
```